Does the order of assigning DataSource to BindingSource and assigning DisplayMember to ComboBox in WinFoms matter?
I found that the following two codes reversing the order of assigning DataSource to the BindingSource and assigning DisplayMember to my ComboBox actually give different results. When I assign the DisplayMember before defining the DataSource like the following codes, the ComboBox actually fails to display my desired DisplayMember (myProtocolInstance.Name), but output "myNameSpace.Protocol". The two messagebox both show a empty string.
Dictionary<string, BindingSource> bs = new Dictionary<string, BindingSource>() {"protocol", new BindingSource()};
this.protocolCombo.DataSource = bs["protocol"];
MessageBox.Show($"{this.protocolCombo.DisplayMember}");  //output: ""
this.protocolCombo.DisplayMember = "Name";
MessageBox.Show($"{this.protocolCombo.DisplayMember}");  //output: ""
bs["protocol"].DataSource = protocol_list;

However when I reverse their orders like this, then the ComboBox correctly shows my desired Name properties from the Protocol instance. And the Messagebox also show more reasonable output, with the first one showing empty string and the second one showing "Name".
Dictionary<string, BindingSource> bs = new Dictionary<string, BindingSource>() {"protocol", new BindingSource()};
this.protocolCombo.DataSource = bs["protocol"];
MessageBox.Show($"{this.protocolCombo.DisplayMember}");  //output: ""
bs["protocol"].DataSource = protocol_list;
this.protocolCombo.DisplayMember = "Name";
MessageBox.Show($"{this.protocolCombo.DisplayMember}");  //output: "Name"

Simiplified version of Protocol class
public class Protocol
{
    public string Name {  get; set; }
    public Protocol(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

I wonder if this is a defect in Winform or it is designed in this way?
Supplementary information: This project is written under .Net6.0

As designed. "Somewhat" contained in the documentation if you read the remarks for the property. If the DisplayMember is invalid (can't be checked against the datasource or can't be found there) keep the previous value of DisplayMember. In your case its still the default an empty string.

Thank all who has answered my question, particularly @Jimi who has given very detailed explaination on the mechanism of DisplayMember and DataSource. For those who come across this post looking for answers of similar question, this is how I finially settle:
Dictionary<string, BindingSource> bs = new Dictionary<string, BindingSource>() {"protocol", new BindingSource()};
this.protocolCombo.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.protocolCombo.ValueMember = "Name";
bs["protocol"].DataSource = new Protocol();
this.protocolCombo.DataSource = bs["protocol"];

I created dummy instances of my various Types (One of them = Class Protocol in this codes) with parameterless constructors to initialize all BindingSource before mounting them to my control elements.
Although the document of BS.DataSource mentions that a non-list Type can be assigned to the DataSource to create a Empty IBindingList of type "T"  (which I think is more reasonble than creating a dummy instance and let the GC  handle it after the initialization?), I can't make it work as VS warns me of "'Protocol' is a 'Type', which is not valid in the given context."
I still appreciate it if anyone can tell me whether this is an acceptable practice and why assigning a non-list Type doesn't work as stated in the document. But anyway, this is how I settle the problem. Thank you all.

The behavior you’re observing is actually by design in Windows Forms, not a defect.
In Windows Forms, the order in which you set the DataSource and DisplayMember properties matters because the ComboBox needs to know what data it is working with before it can correctly interpret the DisplayMember property.
When you set the DisplayMember before the DataSource, the ComboBox doesn’t have any data to bind to yet, so it defaults to displaying the type name.
This behavior is consistent across different versions of .NET, including .NET 6.0

No, this is not correct. A ComboBox - and other Controls - doesn't require this (except the CheckedListBox - for a good reason). If fact, you should always set the DisplayMember (and ValueMember) before the DataSource. Why that is? What actually happens behind the curtain is what causes the current behavior (which is quite predictable, when you know what's happening when these properties are set). You should focus on what the DataSource is set to here, rather then the visual result, or the DisplayMember

Do you mind explainin what "actually happens behind the curtain"?  I can provide another example to erase the possibility of a missunderstanding
Imagine a ComboBox meant to display employee names. If you set DisplayMember to “Name” before setting the DataSource to a list of employees, the ComboBox doesn’t know what “Name” refers to and might display the type name (e.g., “Employee”) instead. Setting the DataSource first ensures the ComboBox knows it’s working with employee objects and can correctly display the “Name” property. @Jimi

It's not like that. You should check the source code, first in relation to the DataSource property, then the DisplayMember property, which goes to the SetDataConnection() method.

What happens, in practice, is that if you set the DisplayMember after the DataSource, the data source must be unmounted and remounted again (so, mounted twice). Unless, as in the current question, the DataSource is actually null (it's just a BindingSource with no source of data). Setting the DisplayMember, in this scenario, cause the DataSource to be mounted from a null source. In this case, setting the DisplayMember first does nothing (there's no data source), setting it after, resets the DataSource. What matters is the way the DataSource is treated, especially when it's initially null

I checked, and you are technically correct. However, your approach seems impractical from a developer’s perspective. Setting the DisplayMember after the DataSource is more developer-friendly, especially for those not deeply familiar with Windows Forms (including myself).
This aligns with Microsoft’s design choices, as their documentation suggests binding the data source first and setting the display member afterward. This way, you don’t have to worry about a null source, and the load is manageable with current technology.

But yes you are technically correct I have to give you this point. And I learned something new. Thank you

Well, the source code and its behaviors are Microsoft's design. The way you set the DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember has always been like this, from a WinForms perspective. The dev is directly responsible for the handling of the source of data. It's important to know how it's treated by the underlying .NET code. Helps quite a bit when you have to analyze performance issues (which can be particularly harsh when it comes to data binding). In general, when the datasource is initially unfilled, you set the DataSource property to a Type (which provides the properties to bind to)

Also important to remember (reading the source code makes it clear): when the DataSource is set to null, the DisplayMember value is set to an empty string (both generate related events when a change occurs). When the DisplayMember is set and the DataSource is not null, the DataSource is unmounted, then remounted (your app is going to be heavily affected by this behavior, if the source of data provides a large number of rows)

@Jimi Do you mind giving some suggestions about "setting the DataSource property to a Type which provides the properties to bind to", as I am too newto go over the source code for the best approach. In my case, the Protocol_List var is created upon user's need at any time during the application (not necessarily at the start) and the DataSource will also change within different Protocol_Lists during running. So should I declare a dummy Protocol_List with the Name Property at the start and mount it to the DataSource, or do so at the appearance of the first real Protocol_List instance? Thank you.

@Jimi And when you talk about the remounting problem of assigning DataSource before DisplayMember, do you refer to the DataSource of the control element (ComboBox in my case) or the DataSource of the BindingSource or both? Is it better to set the DisplayMember before mounting DataSource to both ComboBox and BindingSource?

@alan6690 About your 2° Comment, since it affects the first one: it's related to the DataSource of a Control. A BindingSource doesn't care about the members of the Type it binds to. It only notifies about changes to the internal IBindingListView content, and the changes in the DataSource -- You can set the DataSource of a BS to a Type, which creates an internal empty IBindingList constructed based on that Type. Useful when you handle typed datasets. In your scenario, it's the same thing as setting the BS's DataSource to null

@alan6690 About the 1° comment: it's a common scenario; the source of data of the Control is a BindingSource, which is responsible for notifying data source changes. If its DataSource is null (as it is here), nothing happens. If you then set the DiaplayMember of the Control before the BS's DataSource is set, it's in turn set to an empty string, which creates a virtual paradox. It's more clear if you also try to set the ValueMember at the same time: you get an exception -- Hence, you must to be aware when it's appropriate to set these properties and how this affects the source of data

As a final note (too many comments here), the source code is the actual documentation on the real functionality of the WinForms Controls and Components. The official documentation, quite often unfortunately (even though this has changed recently) refer to best practices, which can be interpreted as: if you don't know what you're doing, do as described here, works in most cases. This generates a cargo cult type of coding: you don't really know why it works, so you don't know why it doesn't work in a slightly different scenario, because the docs cannot cover all
